# BitTorrent: the length of bitfield bigger than the length of pieces

Tags: node.js, p2p, sha1, bittorrent

I know that every bit of bitfield's binary indicates whether there is a file piece in this position. So I think the length of bitfield binary == the length of pieces SHA1 array (20 bytes SHA1), or sometimes the last byte of bitfield is not filled up, it will be slightly larger than the number of pieces SHA1 array (Up to 7).

But the situation I encountered is:

```
bitfield (I received after handshack): 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
```

The length of the bitfield above is: 1733(bytes) => 13864(bits)

So I think the torrent file's pieces should have 13864 SHA1s.

But the pieces field has 262710(bytes) => 262710/20==13136(SHA1s).

Obviously 13864 is much greater than 13136. Why?

Comment: Was that true for all peers in a swarm or did only happen for one? After all clients may have bugs.